# How do create new data frame in R based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, columnsorting

Dataframe looks like this

| fruit | color | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apples | red | 20 |
| apples | orange | 15 |
| apples | green | 11 |

but I want it to be like this

| Apples | Red | green | orange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # | 20 | 11 | 15 |

I am just confused on how to go about this! Hoping to use dplyr

I have tried subsetting the dataframe, but I don't want to make MULTIPLE tibbles for MULTIPLE types of data.
I want it to all be comprised in one dataframe based on the "fruit", but it's all jumbled up in color and amount.

Comment: use `df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = 'color', values_from = 'amount')`. This question is a very common case of spreading a data frame you can find answers easily on this website or any other platforms.

Comment: `library(tidyr) df %>%  pivot_wider(names_from = color, values_from = amount)`